# R while loop with vector condition

Tags: r, function, while-loop, dataframe, vectorization

I want to vectorize a function that uses a while-loop.

The original function is

```
getParamsLeadtime <- function(leadtimeMean, in_tolerance, tolerance){
  searchShape=0
  quantil=0

  # iterates the parameters until the percentage of values is within the interval of tolerance
  while (quantil < in_tolerance){
    searchShape = searchShape+1
    quantil <- pgamma(leadtimeMean+tolerance,shape=searchShape,rate=searchShape/leadtimeMean) -
                  pgamma(leadtimeMean-tolerance,shape=searchShape,rate=searchShape/leadtimeMean) 
  }

  leadtimeShape <- searchShape
  leadtimeRate <- searchShape/leadtimeMean 

  return(c(leadtimeShape, leadtimeRate))
}
```

I would like to have a vectorized call to this function to apply it to a data frame. Currently I am looping through it:

```
leadtimes <- data.frame()

for (a in seq(92:103)) {
  leadtimes <- rbind(leadtimes, getParamsLeadtime(a, .85,2))
}
```

When I tried to vectorize the function, the while did not seem to accept a vector as condition. The following warning occured:

```
Warning message:
In while (input["U"] < rep(tolerance, dim(input)[1])) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

This let me suppose that while does not like vectors. Can you tell me how to vectorize the function?

On a sidenote, I wonder why the column names of the resulting leadtimes-data.frame appear to be values:

```
> leadtimes
   X1     X1.1
1   1 1.000000
2   1 0.500000
3   4 1.333333
4   8 2.000000
5  13 2.600000
6  19 3.166667
7  25 3.571429
8  33 4.125000
9  42 4.666667
10 52 5.200000
11 63 5.727273
12 74 6.166667
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: If you copy the function and the for loop into a R script, it should run. The example data is in the for loop, actually.

Comment: Right you are... sorry!

Comment: You can't vectorize this function. You will always need a loop. However, you should avoid the second circle of the [R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). E.g., you could use `replicate`. If you delve into the statistics you might find an alternative algorithm for your function, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `pgamma` is vectorized - you just need to make sure the args' lengths match up (i.e. `length(shape)` should equal `length(rate)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option that is pretty performant.

We vectorize the calculation of `pgamma` for a given mean lead time, for both the `+tol` and the `-tol` case, over a sufficiently large sequence of `shp`. We calculate a (vectorized) difference, and compare to `in_tol`. The index (minus 1, since we start our sequence at 0) of the first element of the vector that is greater than `in_tol` is the lowest value of `shp` that leads to a pgamma of greater than `in_tol`.

```
f <- function(lead, in_tol, tol) {
  shp <- which(!(pgamma(lead + tol, 0:10000, (0:10000)/lead) - 
                 pgamma(lead - tol, 0:10000, (0:10000)/lead)) 
               < in_tol)[1] - 1
  rate <- shp/lead
  c(shp, rate)
}
```

We can then `sapply` this over a range of mean lead times.

```
t(sapply(1:12, f, 0.85, 2))

##       [,1]     [,2]
##  [1,]    1 1.000000
##  [2,]    1 0.500000
##  [3,]    4 1.333333
##  [4,]    8 2.000000
##  [5,]   13 2.600000
##  [6,]   19 3.166667
##  [7,]   25 3.571429
##  [8,]   33 4.125000
##  [9,]   42 4.666667
## [10,]   52 5.200000
## [11,]   63 5.727273
## [12,]   74 6.166667

system.time(leadtimes <- sapply(1:103, f, 0.85, 2))

##   user  system elapsed 
##   1.28    0.00    1.30
```

You just need to make sure you choose a sensible upper ceiling for the shape parameter (here I've chosen 10000, which was more than generous). Note that if you *don't* choose an upper limit that is high enough, some return values will be `NA`.